# How To Print Multiple Different Data From Same Array?

Tags: python, arrays, database

I want to print multiple different data from the same array, but I don't know how. Can someone show me?
Like I want to print a random letter every time from the same array. Is there a command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can print something random from an Array by generating a random Number and printing that Value from a List:

```
import random

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5] # your list

x = random.randint(0,len(my_list)) # generate a random number from 0-the length of your list

print(my_list[x]) # print the value
```

I believe there is definetly a better solution to this but that is how I would have done it.

Comment: You can put it in a loop if you want to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Python's standard library comes with a `random` module which has methods like

`random.choice(your_list)` which gives you 1 random choice from your array

`random.choices(your_list, n)` which will give you `n` number of choices from your list but there may be duplicates

`random.sample(your_list, n)` which will give you `n` random unique choices from your list

`random.shuffle(your_list)` which will shuffle all the items in your list randomly inplace

Example code

```py
import random

my_list = [1, 2, 5, 3, 9]

print(random.choice(my_list)) # gives 1 random choice
print(random.choices(my_list, 4)) # gives 4 random choices
print(random.sample(my_list, 4) # gives 4 unique choices
random.shuffle(my_list) # shuffles list inplace
print(my_list)
```